# React redirect on click of svg element

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg, react-router

I have a single page React App that is d3 and SVG heavy, and I would like to be able to redirect from one page to another when a user clicks on an `svg rect` on one of my pages. I am familiar with `this.props.history.push()` as well as the `<Link>` component from the react-router-dom library, however neither of these seem to help in this instance.

The svg element of relevance here is deep in a graphing component of mine that is 3-4 children down from the front-end's main `App.js` file that does all of the routing, and when I run `console.log(this.props)` in my component with the svg, there is no `history` object on the props. I'm not sure if a reproducible example is needed here, as I just need direction.

In short, I have no idea what should go into the on-click function that is associated with my svg rect, to enable redirect in my app. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** obviously this is wrong but i tried to return a `Redirect` component in on-click handler and it didn't work:

```
    ...
    ...
    function handleMouseClick() {
        console.log('clicked')
        return <Redirect to='/stats' />;
    } 

    myRect.on('click', handleMouseClick)
    ...
```

**Edit2:** should i put the `rect` elements inside of  components in the svg? is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `history` prop from `react-router` to a component by wrapping it with `withRouter`. Just make sure whatever is mounting your component is using the wrapped version (usually by only exporting the wrapped component).

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/newpage')}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );       
  }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```